# pandas: print names of columns with nonzero elements in row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a bunch of columns where the values are zero or 1. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0]]), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df

    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   0
```

In a given row (say 0), I want to print the names of the nonzero columns. I tried using

```
df.iloc[0].nonzero()
```

but instead of getting `'b', 'd'` (or even [1, 3] as nonzero() is supposed to return indices), I get

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nonzero'
```

(Edit: forget this line: <s>I thought [nonzero() was an method of Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html).</s>)

How can I get the column names as desired?

(Tried searching before asking this, but didn't find any duplicates.)

Comment: what pandas version are you using? the pandas version you are referring to is 0.25.3, plus it specifically states there that it has been deprecated. If you are on pandas 1.1 and above, you could try : ``df.columns[df.ne(0).any()]``

Comment: Ah, good point. Probably a later version: `print(pd.__version__)` yields 1.1.5.    I hit upon `nonzero()` as a method as I was web-searching around trying to get this problem solved.  So, forget I even mentioned a Pandas version or `nonzero()`.  (I will edit the question to remove that part.)  How would I get the column names for the row elements with nonzero values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.iloc[0].loc[lambda df: df.ne(0)].index
Index(['b', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: That does it! And I can wrap it in `list()` if I don't want the `Index()` part.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html), *Series.nonzero()* is replaced by *Series.to_numpy().nonzero()*.

Instead of

```
df.iloc[0].nonzero()
```

Try

```
df.iloc[0].to_numpy().nonzero()
```